# VBS append a child node

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript

i'm trying to add a child node to the GG node.

```
Dim objCurrNode : objCurrNode = "/AA/BB/CC/DD/EE/FF[@name=""Hello""]/GG"
Set objKid = oXML.createElement("HH")
objCurrNode.appendChild (objKid)
```

I get Object required... What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To make `objCurrNode.appendChild objKid` (without (), because you call a Sub) work, `objCurNode` must be an object, it has to be assigned to with Set. The XPath expression

```
"/AA/BB/CC/DD/EE/FF[@name=""Hello""]/GG"
```

can't be used to  create an object, but you could use the .selectSingleNode method to find the node.

Comment: Very nice! Here is what i needed 
    Set objCurrNode = oXML.selectSingleNode = "/AA/BB/CC/DD/EE/FF[@name=""Hello""]/GG"
So happy